# Rails | How to use a Set for a field in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So for one of my rails models, there is any array of strings called `codes`. I would like to ensure that each value in the array is unique. Currently this is accomplished via a function that calls `codes = codes.uniq` on `before_save`.

While this does the job, I'd really like to have the field implemented as a `Set` instead of as an array so that this uniqueness can be guaranteed at all times in the business logic and not just after a save. Is it possible to configure my model so that the `codes` field is implemented as a `Set` instead of as an array within rails (but obviously staying as an array in the database)? Thanks!

Comment: You could probably implement this using `ActiveRecord::Type::Value`. See "Creating Custom Types" section [Here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: @engineersmnky that looks like it'll work! Thanks :)